# Not able to create session with an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I'm trying to implement my first authlogic-based app in ruby on rails. I need to sign user using a custom oauth2 flow, at the end of the process, I want to tell authlogic which user I want him to authenticate. Without providing a login nor password, just directly by passing a user object.

I've found in the README that I can do that using `UserSession.create(user, true)` but putting this at the end of my OAuth callback step is not persisting my user. There is no error nor exception, everything seems to be fine but `UserSession.find` returns nil (even in the next line after the `UserSession.create`). I'm on rails 5.1.6 and authlogic 4.0.1.

User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_authentic
end
```

UserSession model

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
end
```

Thanks in advance for any clues about what I did wrong.

Comment: is the `oauth` callback just being `facebook` calling you `controller#action` ? if so, you just added `UserSession.create(user, true)` at the end of that action?

Comment: it's not that simple as i'm actually using mastodon oauth but that's a completely custom solution. What's important is that, in controller action, i know which user i want to authenticate but i don't want to do that using his email/pass. I just want to authenticate him directly. For the simplicitys sake - let's imagine i have a pretty dumb action which gets last user from DB and logs him in - `UserSession.create(User.last, true)`

Comment: maybe if you do `session = UserSession.create(user, true)` and `put session.errors.full_messages` we could have a better understanding of the issue

Comment: i tried debugging the errors but there are no any (and `session` is `#<UserSession: {:unauthorized_record=>"<protected>"}>`). Btw - the only nonstandard thing in my app is that i don't have email nor login nor password fields in the table. Mentioning that just in case.

Comment: I thought of reading the source code of `UserSession`, but right now I am reading the instruction to set up `authlogic` with rails https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic#2-rails

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found out, from [Authlogic::Session::Base](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/master/lib/authlogic/session/base.rb)

```
module Authlogic
  module Session # :nodoc:
    # This is the most important class in Authlogic. You will inherit this class
    # for your own eg. `UserSession`.
    #
    # Code is organized topically. Each topic is represented by a module. So, to
    # learn about password-based authentication, read the `Password` module.
    #
    # It is common for methods (.initialize and #credentials=, for example) to
    # be implemented in multiple mixins. Those methods will call `super`, so the
    # order of `include`s here is important.
    #
    # Also, to fully understand such a method (like #credentials=) you will need
    # to mentally combine all of its definitions. This is perhaps the primary
    # disadvantage of topical organization using modules.
```

as I read from their instructions, they do never say that you can authenticate user without email and password, but that you can create a session with the `User` object

```
# skip authentication and log the user in directly, the true means "remember me"
UserSession.create(my_user_object, true)
```

I would read more about the `Session.rb`

https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/master/lib/authlogic/session/session.rb

sorry if I can not give you more help

PS you can also debug this gem by setting a binding.pry in the gem files